# Can you change an application.properties at runtime using dockerfile or docker-compose.yml

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have multiple apps that connect to a postgres docker container and I want to change my application.yml files to use or overwrite jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foobardb from the application properties of each app to to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9072/foobardb wherein i'm changing the default 5432 port to 9072 port of the my postgres docker container.

Is there way to configure this using a shell script and mount it to a dockerfile or docker-compose.yml

Comment: you don't mention what's reading `application.yml`, but many configs can be overwritten by environment variables, which is usually a simpler approach to runtime configuration.  Is this spring ?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Hi Dan sorry about that, yes this is a springboot app. Wherein I have 3 apps that are running in different docker containers which is currently connected to the default 5432 postgres port on my machine, I would like to dynamically configure the application.yml files of each of those apps during runtime to point to the right postgres (container) in port 9072. It’s either when I run my postgres container I have a script to check the application.yml file of each app and set it to 9072 or the other way around wherein when I run the apps it will look for the 9072 port and overwrite the current one

Comment: Did you see the link?  It shows how an environment variable can be used to override the setting in your applicationyml, which is preferable to dynamically rewriting configuration files when supported

Comment: Yes I’m re writing my scripts right now thanks Dan!